# Determining HD Content

Tags: storage

A storage system has 6 hard drives set up as RAID 5, where HD 6 is the parity disk using odd parity. One day, the system crashes due to failure of HD4. During recovery, we find out that HD1 stores 11110000; HD2 contains 10011100; HD3 contains 00011000; HD5 contains 10101010 and the parity disk contains 11110111.

What would be the content of HD4?

Comment: Hello! We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it. Assuming you tried to solve it yourself and got stuck, it may be helpful if you wrote your thoughts and what you could not figure out. It will definitely draw more answers to your post. We do not want to just do your exercise for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion.

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about RAID5?  since you say HD6 is the parity disk, maybe you mean RAID4?  (in RAID5, all HDs contain parities, so there's no single HD for parity).

Comment: This does not strike me as a computer *science* problem. It'd maybe more at home on [SU]?

Comment: @Raphael Na, it's a classic computer-architecture question. It's clearly on topic here.

Answer (score 2):

A parity determines whether the amount of particular occurrences for something is even or odd. In this case, since the parity is odd, that means HD 6 stores a `1` for an odd amount of `1`s in that index for the remaining HDs and a `0` for an even amount of `1`s in that index.

Let's go over the contents again:

```
HD 1: 11110000
HD 2: 10011100
HD 3: 00011000
HD 4: ????????
HD 5: 10101010
HD 6: 11110111
```

This tells us that all indices contain an odd amount of `1`s when summing them from the remaining 5 HDs except the 3rd index (counting from 0 on the right), which has a `0` denoting an even amount of `1`s.

For each index, we can determine whether the remaining HD 4 contained a `0` or a `1` by matching the expected parity:

```
HD 1: 11110000
HD 2: 10011100
HD 3: 00011000
HD 4: 00101001
HD 5: 10101010
HD 6: 11110111
```

You can confirm that this is correct by counting the amount of occurrences of `1` in each column excluding HD 6.